# Angular Ui Grid Import Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am new to Angular Ui Grid. I currently have a grid that supports export and import for csv files, but having an issue with the import feature.

I have a preset data mocking information coming from database. which would give me something like this example below

[Grid Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvthI.jpg)

I try to import new data shown below

[New Grid with different columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0o2P.jpg)

To be more clear. I want to add the new data **(second picture)** to the grid in the first picture, but completely remove the information (data and columns) from the grid in the first picture.

In other words i want the imported data to overwrite the previous data found in the same grid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From question it is unclear how you bind data to grid? `ui-grid="{ data: myData }"` like this only?

If your data format and column definations are differnt then you need to setup them explicitly like this,

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

gridOptions1 = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
          { name:'firstName', field: 'first-name' },
          { name:'1stFriend', field: 'friends[0]' },
          { name:'city', field: 'address.city'},
          { name:'getZip', field: 'getZip()', enableCellEdit:false}
        ],
        data : [      {
                           "first-name": "Cox",
                           "friends": ["friend0"],
                           "address": {street:"301 Dove Ave", city:"Laurel", zip:"39565"},
                           "getZip" : function() {return this.address.zip;}
                       }
                   ]
      };
  
gridOptions2 = {
        enableSorting: true,
        columnDefs: [
          { name:'firstName1', field: 'first-name1' },
          { name:'1stFriend1', field: 'friends1[0]' },
          { name:'city1', field: 'address1.city'}
        ],
        data : [      {
                           "first-name1": "Cox1",
                           "friends1": ["friend1"],
                           "address1": {street:"301 Dove Ave1", city:"Laurel1", zip:"395651"}
                       }
                   ]
      };
  
  $scope.gridOptions = gridOptions1;

  $scope.changeBinding = function(){
    
      $scope.gridOptions = gridOptions2;
  }
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">  
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit class="grid"></div>
    <button ng-click="changeBinding()">Change</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have used same example given in [ui-grid documentaion](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding)

**Update**: Changed to have gridoptions dynamic. If data content from obj[0] and obj[1] are correct then you must able to switch grid data and options.

Comment: i am currently using something as follows.                  `self.gridOptions.data = obj[0].data;` and `self.gridOptions.columnDefs = obj[1].Data`                                                                                          where **obj[0]** contains the data for each row and **obj[1]** the column names. I'll try to be more clear in my question. currently updating it